# How to assign frame to controller dynamically in iphone?

Tags: objective-c, frame

I know its silly question to ask but I am new to ipad and my app supports both mode landscape as well as portrait.I want to assign frame to every controller(labels, buttons, etc) in such a way that in whatever mode the controller remain in proper alignment.Please can anyone tell me how I can assign frame to controllers?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Don't confuse controllers to views. Views have frames. First of all you will have to enable rotation by returning `YES` for all supported orientation in `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` method. Then you can declare a method that sets up the views for an orientation passed as argument. Define frames for each subview in each orientation.

Then call this method from `layoutSubviews` and/or any of the methods called during an orientation change like `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:`

You can also look at `Autoresize Masks`.